# Как более эффективно и правильно написать код таймера?

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Есть код, который я нашел на стороннем сайте, я сделал так, чтобы он разделял значения на разные ячейки, все получилось и все работает, но хотелось бы выяснить, можно ли сделать условия как-то по другому, т.к. знаю что такой подход не является хорошим тоном. Может кто знает более легкий способ для реализации такой идеи?

Вот пример условий которые меня беспокоят:

```
    if (('' + t.days).length === 2) {
      daysFirst.innerHTML    = ('' + t.days).slice(0, 1);
      daysLast.innerHTML     = ('' + t.days).slice(-1);
    } else {
      daysFirst.innerHTML    = '0';
      daysLast.innerHTML     = ('' + t.days).slice(-1);
    }
    if (('' + t.hours).length === 2) {
      hoursFirst.innerHTML   = ('' + t.hours).slice(0, 1);
      hoursLast.innerHTML    = ('' + t.hours).slice(-1);        
    } else {
      hoursFirst.innerHTML    = '0'; 
      hoursLast.innerHTML    = ('' + t.hours).slice(-1);
    }
    if (('' + t.minutes).length === 2) {
      minutesFirst.innerHTML = ('' + t.minutes).slice(0, 1);
      minutesLast.innerHTML  = ('' + t.minutes).slice(-1);        
    } else {
      minutesFirst.innerHTML  = '0'; 
      minutesLast.innerHTML  = ('' + t.minutes).slice(-1);
    }
    if (('' + t.seconds).length === 2) {
      secondsFirst.innerHTML = ('' + t.seconds).slice(0, 1);
      secondsLast.innerHTML  = ('' + t.seconds).slice(-1);         
    } else {
      secondsFirst.innerHTML  = '0';   
      secondsLast.innerHTML  = ('' + t.seconds).slice(-1);
    }
```

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var 
    clock       = document.getElementById(id),
    daysFirst    = clock.querySelector('.days-first'),
    daysLast    = clock.querySelector('.days-last'),
    hoursFirst   = clock.querySelector('.hours-first'),
    hoursLast   = clock.querySelector('.hours-last'),
    minutesFirst = clock.querySelector('.minutes-first'),
    minutesLast = clock.querySelector('.minutes-last'),
    secondsFirst = clock.querySelector('.seconds-first'),
    secondsLast = clock.querySelector('.seconds-last');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    if (('' + t.days).length === 2) {
      daysFirst.innerHTML    = ('' + t.days).slice(0, 1);
      daysLast.innerHTML     = ('' + t.days).slice(-1);
    } else {
      daysFirst.innerHTML    = '0';
      daysLast.innerHTML     = ('' + t.days).slice(-1);
    }
    if (('' + t.hours).length === 2) {
      hoursFirst.innerHTML   = ('' + t.hours).slice(0, 1);
      hoursLast.innerHTML    = ('' + t.hours).slice(-1);        
    } else {
      hoursFirst.innerHTML    = '0'; 
      hoursLast.innerHTML    = ('' + t.hours).slice(-1);
    }
    if (('' + t.minutes).length === 2) {
      minutesFirst.innerHTML = ('' + t.minutes).slice(0, 1);
      minutesLast.innerHTML  = ('' + t.minutes).slice(-1);        
    } else {
      minutesFirst.innerHTML  = '0'; 
      minutesLast.innerHTML  = ('' + t.minutes).slice(-1);
    }
    if (('' + t.seconds).length === 2) {
      secondsFirst.innerHTML = ('' + t.seconds).slice(0, 1);
      secondsLast.innerHTML  = ('' + t.seconds).slice(-1);         
    } else {
      secondsFirst.innerHTML  = '0';   
      secondsLast.innerHTML  = ('' + t.seconds).slice(-1);
    }
    
    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline="January 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0300"; 
var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

```css
body{
 text-align: center;
 background: #00ECB9;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}

h1{
  color: #396;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 40px 0px 20px;
}

#clockdiv{
 font-family: sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
 display: inline-block;
 font-weight: 100;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 30px;
}

#clockdiv > div{
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: #00BF96;
 display: inline-block;
}

#clockdiv div > span{
 padding: 15px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: #00816A;
 display: inline-block;
}

.smalltext{
 padding-top: 5px;
 font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Countdown Clock</h1>
<div id="clockdiv">
  <div>
    <span class="days-first"></span>
    <span class="days-last"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="hours-first"></span>
    <span class="hours-last"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="minutes-first"></span>
    <span class="minutes-last"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="seconds-first"></span>
    <span class="seconds-last"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: вам обратный отчет нужен?

Comment: Таймер уже работает, но я сомневаюсь насчет проверки, тк она очень большая и я думаю что не есть хорошо такое вытворять, я же написал все подробно. Можете нажать на кнопку выполнить и увидите, что таймер работает

Comment: главное не забывать что при уходе окна в фон таймер будет выполняться реже чем указанный интервал

Comment: @teran К счастью, код не использует `setInterval` для отсчета времени.

Comment: @Igor не вчитывался, но это там зачем `var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);` ?

Comment: @teran По интервалу происходит обновление DOM-элементов, время вычисляется правильно.

Comment: @Igor а, действительно. зер гут.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    function updateComponent(el1, el2, value) {
      var str = '' + value;
      if (str.length !== 2) {
        str = '0' + str;
      }
      el1.innerHTML = str.slice(0, 1);
      el2.innerHTML = str.slice(-1);
    }

    updateComponent(daysFirst, daysLast, t.days);
    updateComponent(hoursFirst, hoursLast, t.hours);
    updateComponent(minutesFirst, minutesLast, t.minutes);
    updateComponent(secondsFirst, secondsLast, t.seconds);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно так, немного больше DRY

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var 
    clock       = document.getElementById(id),
    daysFirst    = clock.querySelector('.days-first'),
    daysLast    = clock.querySelector('.days-last'),
    hoursFirst   = clock.querySelector('.hours-first'),
    hoursLast   = clock.querySelector('.hours-last'),
    minutesFirst = clock.querySelector('.minutes-first'),
    minutesLast = clock.querySelector('.minutes-last'),
    secondsFirst = clock.querySelector('.seconds-first'),
    secondsLast = clock.querySelector('.seconds-last');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime),
        days = t.days.toString(),
        hours = t.hours.toString(),
        minutes = t.minutes.toString(),
        seconds = t.seconds.toString();

    daysFirst.innerHTML = days.length === 2 ? days.slice(0, 1) : 0;
    daysLast.innerHTML = days.slice(-1);
    
    hoursFirst.innerHTML = hours.length === 2 ? hours.slice(0, 1) : 0;
    hoursLast.innerHTML = hours.slice(-1);
    
    minutesFirst.innerHTML = minutes.length === 2 ? minutes.slice(0, 1) : 0;
    minutesLast.innerHTML = minutes.slice(-1);
    
    secondsFirst.innerHTML = seconds.length === 2 ? seconds.slice(0, 1) : 0;
    secondsLast.innerHTML = seconds.slice(-1);
    
    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline="January 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0300"; 
var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

```css
body{
 text-align: center;
 background: #00ECB9;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}

h1{
  color: #396;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 40px 0px 20px;
}

#clockdiv{
 font-family: sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
 display: inline-block;
 font-weight: 100;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 30px;
}

#clockdiv > div{
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: #00BF96;
 display: inline-block;
}

#clockdiv div > span{
 padding: 15px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: #00816A;
 display: inline-block;
}

.smalltext{
 padding-top: 5px;
 font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Countdown Clock</h1>
<div id="clockdiv">
  <div>
    <span class="days-first"></span>
    <span class="days-last"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="hours-first"></span>
    <span class="hours-last"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="minutes-first"></span>
    <span class="minutes-last"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="seconds-first"></span>
    <span class="seconds-last"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Была такая мысль, но тоже большая конструкция..